# Minimum Distance for "Speed of Light Approach"

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, speed-of-light

I tried to calculate the minimum distance between a planet and a test mass for the mass to attain the speed of light on colliding with the planet's surface if it were released from rest at the initial point. This is what I came up with:
The acceleration of the test mass ($m$) is given by $$a = -GM/x^2,$$ 
where $a, G, M$ and $x$ are the acceleration of the test mass, universal gravitational constant, mass of the planet and instantaneous distance of the planet from the mass respectively.
On writing $a$ as $vdv/dx$, we finally obtain the following expression: $$vdv=-GMdx/x^2,$$ which we can integrate as follows: $$\int_0^c{vdv}=-\int_{d_o}^R{GMdx/x^2}$$
Here, $c, R $ and $d_o$ are the speed of light, the radius of the planet and the initial distance (which we wish to find) between the planet and $m$. The above integration will ultimately give us the relation, $$c^2 = 2GM(\frac {1}{R} - \frac{1}{d_o}),$$or simply put, $$d_o=\frac{2GMR}{2GM-Rc^2}$$ meaning that for a finite positive value of $d_o$, $$M/R> c^2/2G$$
This is where I have a problem: why is there a restriction on $M$ and $R$ for such a value of $d_o$ to exist? Also, if such a dense planet did exist, would it be possible for a body moving towards it to attain the speed of light (in an isolated system)?

Comment: There is no such distance.  As the speed of the test mass gets approaches the speed of light, its mass increases.  More and more of the additional potential energy will be converted to mass instead of speed as the speed gets closer and closer, but never reaches, the speed of light.

Comment: No [the mass doesn't increase](http://www.itep.ru/theor/persons/lab180/okun/em_3.pdf). It's the [$\gamma$-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) which increases, the mass remains invariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bring an object from infinity to a distance $R$ then the potential energy change is:

$$ \Delta U = -\frac{GMm}{R} $$

Assuming your object starts at rest, the potential energy change is equal to the change in kinetic energy, so we have:

$$ \frac{GMm}{R} = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

so:

$$ v^2 = \frac{2GM}{R} $$

You want $v \ge c$, so:

$$ \frac{2GM}{R} \ge c^2 $$

which is the same as your result give or take a bit of algebra.

I should make the obligatory note that because this calculation is non-relativistic it is (almost) devoid of physical meaning. I say *almost* because actually $2GM/c^2$ is the [Schwarzschild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) i.e. the radius of the event horizon for a black hole of mass $M$. However the Schwarzschild radius $r$ is not the same as the radius used in Newtonian mechanics. Thre is a superficial similarity but it is misleading.

Comment: That is the formula for the Schwarzschild radius. You should think about boldening your final remark. I almost didn't catch it on the first read and was about to downvote your answer for not mentioning SR.